# SWT Canvas fails to redraw on Windows but works on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, canvas, swt, redraw

```
this.canvas = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
```

I'm using a PaintListener:

```
this.canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
        // Draw images
        synchronized (imageMarks) {
            for (ImageMark mark : Whiteboard.this.imageMarks)
            {
                Image image = Whiteboard.this.getImage(mark.id);
                Point position = ScaledPoint.toSWTPoint(Whiteboard.this.getCanvasSize(), mark.getPosition());
                Point bounds = mark.getUnscaledBoundaries(Whiteboard.this.getCanvasSize());
                e.gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getBounds().width, image.getBounds().height, position.x, position.y, 
                        bounds.x, bounds.y);
            }
        }

        // Draw pencil marks
        synchronized (pencilMarks) {
            e.gc.setLineWidth(LINE_WIDTH);
            for (double[] line : Whiteboard.this.pencilMarks)
            {
                Point lastPosPoint = ScaledPoint.toSWTPoint(Whiteboard.this.getCanvasSize(), new ScaledPoint(line[0], line[2]));
                Point newPosPoint = ScaledPoint.toSWTPoint(Whiteboard.this.getCanvasSize(), new ScaledPoint(line[1], line[3]));
                e.gc.drawLine(lastPosPoint.x, lastPosPoint.y, newPosPoint.x, newPosPoint.y);
            }
        }

        // Draw pointer, assuming it's there
        if (pointerMark != null)
        {
            synchronized (pointerMark) {
                Point pos = ScaledPoint.toSWTPoint(Whiteboard.this.getCanvasSize(), pointerMark.getPosition());
                if (pointerMark.isFlipped())
                    e.gc.drawImage(Whiteboard.pointerImageFlipped, pos.x, pos.y);
                else
                    e.gc.drawImage(Whiteboard.pointerImage, pos.x, pos.y);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

and redrawing the canvas via a canvas.redraw() call. On 64-bit Linux, this seems to be working without any issues, but strangely enough, on 64-bit Windows, nothing ever ends up being erased or redrawn. For example, if the screen is resized, the pencil markings do not resize as well, they just end up being cut out of the screen. When new marks are added (in other words, when the paint listener is called again), the repositioned markings are redrawn on top of the old ones which didn't scale with the window. In other words, I believe the canvas is not being cleared upon canvas.redraw(). Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying SWT.NO_BACKGROUND which stops the Canvas being cleared before each paint.

If you use SWT.NO_BACKGROUND it is your paint method's responsibility to draw every pixel of the Canvas.

SWT.NO_BACKGROUND JavaDoc:

> By default, before a widget paints, the client area is filled with the
>   current background. When this style is specified, the background is
>   not filled, and the application is responsible for filling every pixel
>   of the client area. This style might be used as an alternative to
>   "double-buffering" in order to reduce flicker. This style does not
>   mean "transparent" - widgets that are obscured will not draw through.

Comment: This works, although I wonder why each platform implements such different behavior. After adding a couple lines: e.gc.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE)); e.gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, Whiteboard.this.getCanvasSize().x, Whiteboard.this.getCanvasSize().y); the screen seems to redraw correctly, although now there's a strong flickering on the Windows app that isn't on the Linux version

Comment: You may find the `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` flag helps with the flickering.